# Mergefield for objectname of PDF using Access and VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to have the name of my PDF be text that is in the report itself.

For example:

The PDF report generated has 'Project: Project X, Date: June 2019' text in it. I want the PDF to be saved as 'Project X June 2019'. I don't want to right click Save As and then type it in because this is prone to user error.

I've attached some code below - currently it saves all the PDFs as 'Report.PDF'. I'm not really sure how to go about this. Any help would be much appreciated.

`DoCmd.OpenReport "qryRptInvoice", acViewPreview, , "[InvoiceID] = " & Me.InvoiceID`

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "qryRptInvoice", acFormatPDF, "Report.PDF", True
```

Comment: You accomplish this by concatenating static text with a variable. How should Access know to use `June 2019`? Is there a textbox on form with this info? Do you just want to use the current month and year?

Answer (score 2):

Accomplish this by concatenating static text with variable input.

Can reference controls on form that have values input/selected by user. If you want project name as well as month/year:

`DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "qryRptInvoice", acFormatPDF, Me.tbxProject & Format(Me.tbxDate, " MMMM YYYY") & ".PDF", True`

If you want 3-letter month name then use `" MMM YYYY"`.

Can use current date as input but if June report is run on July 1, then the file name will be wrong.